How to handle values starting with double quotes in papaparse
Using latest Papaparse to parse large CSV files.
It handles double quotes in the value but not when value starts with double quotes.
Using this code:
const parsePromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    Papa.parse<Equipment>(fileStream, {
        header: true,
        delimiter: "\t",
        dynamicTyping: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        step: (result) => {
            const rowData = {
                vehicle_id: result.data.vehicle_id,
                schema_id: result.data.schema_id,
                option_id: result.data.option_id,
                record_id: result.data.record_id,
                location: result.data.location,
                data_value: result.data.data_value,
                condition: result.data.condition,
            };
            entities.push(rowData);
            console.log(rowData)
        },
        complete: () => resolve(),
        error: (error) => reject(error),
    });
});

If I have the following csv data:
vehicle_id  schema_id   option_id   record_id   location    data_value  condition
425972620240523 15102   1266    7700    W   "Första hjälpen"- förbandslåda med varningstriangel, 2 varselvästar 
425972620240523 15104   1266    7700    W   W   
425972620240523 15101   1266    7800    INT S   
425972620240523 15102   1266    7800    INT medical kit, warning triangle, 2 safety vests   
425972620240523 15104   1266    7800    INT INT 
425972620240523 15101   1267    7900    W   S   
425972620240523 15102   1267    7900    W   Papperskorg (borttagbar)    

It outputs
{
  vehicle_id: 425972620240523,
  schema_id: 15102,
  option_id: 1266,
  record_id: 7700,
  location: 'W',
  data_value: 'Första hjälpen"- förbandslåda med varningstriangel, 2 varselvästar\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15104\t1266\t7700\tW\tW\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15101\t1266\t7800\tINT\tS\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15102\t1266\t7800\tINT\tmedical kit, warning triangle, 2 safety vests\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15104\t1266\t7800\tINT\tINT\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15101\t1267\t7900\tW\tS\t\r\n' +
    '425972620240523\t15102\t1267\t7900\tW\tPapperskorg (borttagbar)\t\r\n',
  condition: undefined
}

If I move the first double quote as in:
vehicle_id  schema_id   option_id   record_id   location    data_value  condition
425972620240523 15102   1266    7700    W   Första "hjälpen"- förbandslåda med varningstriangel, 2 varselvästar 
425972620240523 15104   1266    7700    W   W   
425972620240523 15101   1266    7800    INT S   
425972620240523 15102   1266    7800    INT medical kit, warning triangle, 2 safety vests   
425972620240523 15104   1266    7800    INT INT 
425972620240523 15101   1267    7900    W   S   
425972620240523 15102   1267    7900    W   Papperskorg (borttagbar)    


The result is correct:
{
  vehicle_id: 425972620240523,
  schema_id: 15102,
  option_id: 1266,
  record_id: 7700,
  location: 'W',
  data_value: 'Första "hjälpen"- förbandslåda med varningstriangel, 2 varselvästar',
  condition: null
}
{
  vehicle_id: 425972620240523,
  schema_id: 15104,
  option_id: 1266,
  record_id: 7700,
  location: 'W',
  data_value: 'W',
  condition: null
}
....

How can Papaparse handle values starting with a double quote?

RFC-4180 says "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."

You can add a quoteChar atribute to the config with a value different than " to disable this feature

thanks @KrzysztofKrzeszewski it seems to work with the combination of quoteChar: '' and escapeChar: '',
